# Field Collection RESTful API rendered in HTML

Tags: json, rest, api, drupal-views, drupal-8

I'm not sure this is a bug or what. But when I create API view page and add field (which is field collection), it rendered HTML instead of 'neat' JSON.

For example it should be look like :

```
field_collection_name: [
   {
     "title": "Big Title"
     "field_a": "content"
   },
   {
     "title": "Big Title 2"
     "field_a": "content 2"
   },
   {
     "title": "Big Title 3"
     "field_a": "content 3"
   }
]
```

Instead, the JSON in api view render like this:

```
field_collection_name: <div class="field--name-title">Big Title</div><div class="field--name-field_a">content</div><div class="field--name-title">Big Title2</div><div class="field--name-field_a">content 2</div><div class="field--name-title">Big Title 3</div><div class="field--name-field_a">content 3</div>
```

Anyone experience same problem like this before? Any settings need to set for field collection?

Comment: Well, this suck. No one answer my question

Comment: Could you export your Views, using the `drush cex` or the Export interface ? You could then link it here from a Gist (the code of exported views is pretty long & ugly to be printed on Stackoverflow) ? So someone could import it and reproduce your issue, and finally help you.

Comment: By the way, Field Collection for Drupal 8 is deprecated. The official documentation says **Paragraphs is likely to replace field collection for Drupal 8. Field collection is on its way to being deprecated. It is recommended to use paragraphs instead of field collection for Drupal 8 projects.**