# Drupal 8 - Multiple fieldset in content type

Tags: json, content-type, drupal-8, fieldset

I can create group (I use fieldset) in "manage form display". How to multiple the group just like field collection can do. I don't want use field collection because it can't generate JSON in API view. As I already post at [Field Collection RESTful API rendered in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489797/field-collection-restful-api-rendered-in-html) but not one reply.

[image]

So, how to multiple the fieldset ? Like have a "Add Item" button below the fieldset and add fieldset after click the button.

Millions of thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with Field Groups. There is a Field Collection alpha for Drupal 8. However, I use [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) in almost all my builds to get the same result. It is more challenging to configure but also very flexible.